# DN - Java JDNI LDAP - Common name vs User Id

Tags: java, ldap, distinguishedname

Common name, lets say "John Smith" is used compose the DN, but is it posible to compose a full DN using UID.

Im currently doing this and it works.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable(11);
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://myDomain.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=John Smith,OU=IT,OU=MyCompany,OU=Users,DC=myDomain,DC=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "myPassWrd");
```

Now I want to use `UID`, for example J.smith, for authentication instead of his full name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
 env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
 env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
```

Works for me.

Comment: @MichelBehlok Well the username string has to match whatever is in the directory.

Comment: thanks so much. @MichelBehlok Your solution of adding the at-domain was perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In our LDAP autenthication routines, we create a `jndi` user account that the application uses to authenticate itself in the LDAP, once the application stablishes the connection using the distinguished name of the jndi user (example: `uid=jndi,ou=branch,dc=com,dc=your,dc=organization`) then (provided a branch for the user nodes in the tree) it uses the following code to check if the user `uid` is in the LDAP tree:

```
public String findUserDnByBranchAndUid(String branchName, String uid) throws NamingException {
    SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
    searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    searchControls.setCountLimit(1);

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer;
    answer = dirContext.search(branchName, String.format("(uid=%s)", uid), searchControls);

    if (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = answer.nextElement();
        return searchResult.getNameInNamespace();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
String userDn = findUserDnByBranchAndUid("ou=users,dc=com,dc=your,dc=organization", "jsmith");
```

If `userDn` is not empty, then the user exists in the tree, then we proceed to establish a new conection using that DN (and the user password) instead of the jndi user DN.

If everithing goes well, then the user `jsmith` is logged in with it's credentials with just his/her id, without providing any not user-friendly DN.